# Making use of allocators in a custom container class

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I'm developing a container-like class and I would like to make use of the standard allocator infrastructure much like the standard containers. On the net I find a lot of material about how to use the `std::allocator` class alone, or how to define a custom allocator for standard containers, but the material about how to make generically use of an standard conforming allocator is very rare, in particular in the context of C++11, where things seem to be much easier from the point of view of who writes a custom allocator, but more complex from the container's point of view.

So my question is about how to correctly make use of a standard conforming allocator in the most generic way, specifically:

- First of all, when should I design a custom container in this way? Is there a sensible performance overhead (including missing optimization opportunities) in using the default allocator instead of plain new/delete?
- Do I have to explicitly call contained objects' destructors?
- How do I discriminate between stateful and stateless allocators?
- How to handle stateful allocators?

  - When (if ever) are two instances interchangeable (when can I destroy with one instance the memory allocated with another one)?
  - They have to be copied when the container is copied?
  - They can/have to be moved when the container is moved?
  - In the container's move constructor and move assignment operator, when can I move the pointer to allocated memory, and when do I have to allocate different memory and move the elements instead?
- Are there issues about exception safety in this context?

I'm specifically interested in an answer about the C++11 world (does it change anything in C++14?)

Comment: Allocators are usually used as a base class of your container.  That way a stateless allocator does not make your container larger because of The Empty Base Class Optimization (EBCO).

Comment: If someone wanted to locate one std::map in regular memory and another map in shared memory, changing the allocator supports that while changing new/delete would not.

Comment: You may wish to familiarize yourself with [std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) and with the behavior of the C++11 containers w.r.t copy/move/assign/swap, e.g. [vector::operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)

Comment: Is this behavior commonly specified in the standard for all the containers, or each has its own quirks?

Comment: @gigabytes It's specified for all appropriate containers in 23.2.1 General Container Requirements [container.requirements.general]/13: "All of the containers defined in this Clause [clause 23 defines the standard containers] and in (21.4) [21.4 is `basic_string`] except `array` meet the additional requirements of an allocator-aware container, as described in Table 99."

Comment: @gigabytes Because you said *standard* allocator infrastructure, I doubt you will find much use for this but BloombergLP's open source BSL library also introduces an allocator mechanism that follows a slightly different approach:
https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/wiki/BDE-Allocator-model

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In all answers below, I'm assuming you want to follow the rules for C++11 std-defined containers.  The standard does not require you to write your custom containers this way.

> - First of all, when should I design a custom container in this way? Is there a sensible performance overhead (including missing
>     optimization opportunities) in using the default allocator instead of
>     plain new/delete?

One of the most common and effective uses for custom allocators is to have it allocate off of the stack, for performance reasons.  If your custom container can not accept such an allocator, then your clients will not be able to perform such an optimization.

> - Do I have to explicitly call contained objects' destructors?

You have to explicitly call `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(alloc, ptr)`, which in turn will either directly call the `value_type`'s destructor, or will call the `destroy` member of the `allocator_type`.

> - How do I discriminate between stateful and stateless allocators?

I would not bother.  Just assume the allocator is stateful.

> - How to handle stateful allocators?

Follow the rules laid out in C++11 very carefully.  Especially those for allocator-aware containers specified in [container.requirements.general].  The rules are too numerous to list here.  However I'm happy to answer specific questions on any of those rules.  But step one is get a copy of the standard, and read it, at least the container requirements sections.  I recommend [the latest C++14 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) for this purpose.

> - When (if ever) are two instances interchangeable (when can I destroy with one instance the memory allocated with another one)?

If two allocators compare equal, then either can deallocate pointers allocated from the other.  Copies (either by copy construction or copy assignment) are required to compare equal.

> - They have to be copied when the container is copied?

Search the standard for `propagate_on` and `select_on_container_copy_construction` for the nitty gritty details.  The nutshell answer is "it depends."

> - They can/have to be moved when the container is moved?

Have to be for move construction.  Move assignment depends on `propagate_on_container_move_assignment`.

> - In the container's move constructor and move assignment operator, when can I move the pointer to allocated memory, and when do I have to allocate different memory
>     and move the elements instead?

The newly move constructed container should have gotten its allocator by move constructing the rhs's allocator.  These two allocators are required to compare equal.  So you can transfer memory ownership for all allocated memory for which your container has a valid state for that pointer being `nullptr` in the rhs.

The move assignment operator is arguably the most complicated:  The behavior depends on `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` and whether or not the two allocators compare equal.  A more complete description is below in my "allocator cheat sheet."

> - Are there issues about exception safety in this context?

Yes, tons.  [allocator.requirements] lists the allocator requirements, which the container can depend on.  This includes which operations can and can not throw.

You will also need to deal with the possibility that the allocator's `pointer` is not actually a `value_type*`.  [allocator.requirements] is also the place to look for these details.

Good luck.  This is not a beginner project.  If you have more specific questions, post them to SO.  To get started, go straight to the standard.  I am not aware of any other authoritative source on the subject.

Here is a cheat-sheet I made for myself which describes allocator behavior, and the container's special members.  It is written in English, not standard-eze.  If you find any discrepancies between my cheat sheet, and the C++14 working draft, trust the working draft.  One known discrepancy is that I've added `noexcept` specs in ways the standard has not.

---

> Allocator behavior:
>
> ```
> C() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value);
>
> C(const C& c);
> ```
>
> Gets allocator from `alloc_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(c)`.
>
> ```
> C(const C& c, const allocator_type& a);
> ```
>
> Gets allocator from `a`.
>
> ```
> C(C&& c)
>   noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible<allocator_type>::value && ...);
> ```
>
> Gets allocator from `move(c.get_allocator())`, transfers resources.
>
> ```
> C(C&& c, const allocator_type& a);
> ```
>
> Gets allocator from `a`.  Transfers resources if `a == c.get_allocator()`.
>   Move constructs from each `c[i]` if `a != c.get_allocator()`.
>
> ```
> C& operator=(const C& c);
> ```
>
> If `alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value` is `true`,
>   copy assigns allocators.  In this case, if allocators are not equal prior
>   to assignment, dumps all resources from `*this`.
>
> ```
> C& operator=(C&& c)
>   noexcept(
>     allocator_type::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value &&
>     is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value);
> ```
>
> If `alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `true`,
>   dumps resources, move assigns allocators, and transfers resources from `c`.
>
> If `alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `false`
>   and `get_allocator() == c.get_allocator()`, dumps resources, and transfers
>   resources from `c`.
>
> If `alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `false`
>   and `get_allocator() != c.get_allocator()`, move assigns each `c[i]`.
>
> ```
> void swap(C& c)
>   noexcept(!allocator_type::propagate_on_container_swap::value ||
>            __is_nothrow_swappable<allocator_type>::value);
> ```
>
> If `alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_swap::value` is `true`, swaps
>   allocators.  Regardless, swaps resources.  Undefined behavior if the
>   allocators are unequal and `propagate_on_container_swap::value` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, "which is the correct usage?" was too vague... In the last bullet when I talk about "move constructors" I should have written "move constructor and move assignment operator". Of course in the move constructor the only thing to do is to move the resource, but what about assignment? I've edited the question.

Comment: Question updated.  The best info is in my "cheat sheet", under `C& operator=(C&& c)`.

Comment: if alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment is false and get_allocator() != c.get_allocator(), move assigns each c[i]. But if the size of the source container is different (suppose it's a container similar to vector) what should I do? Resize and then move assign each c[i]? This would cause a call to the move constructor of the elements, and then the move assignment operator. Or do I have to allocate new uninitialized memory, delete the others, and then move-construct instead of move-assign the elements? I suppose this is a container-specific detail, isn't it? What does vector do?

Comment: The libc++ vector calls the member `assign(iter, iter)` using `move_iterator` adaptors for the rhs iterators.  The member `assign` will reallocate if necessary, moving elements from the old buffer to  the new in that case.  Then it will assign to existing elements, and construct new elements on the end if needed, or erase elements from the end if needed.  http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/vector

Comment: Ok, fine! So saying that "libc++ vector does this" you're implying that the standard does not dictate this specific thing?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, libc++ is conforming in this matter.  Table 99 describes the requirements of the allocator-aware container move assignment operator on the row that starts with `a = rv`.  The requirements also list the requirements on the `value_type`.  And the vector move assignment operator can not perform any operation on the `value_type` not listed here.  Everything else is QOI.  This particular operator is not (for example) allowed to default construct the `value_type`.  But I stop short of bounding/defining all legal implementations (that is a larger, non-trivial task).

Comment: @gigabytes Are you sure that you cannot write your container on top of one of the existing Standard Containers or using Boost.MultiIndex? Because you will not only have to worry about allocator stuff, but also about move semantics, iterator invalidation and many other subtleties. At the very least, do you **thoroughly understand** the libstdc++ or libc++ implementation of `std::vector`? If not, then this is a very ambitious project.

Comment: @TemplateRex, yours is a valid point! I'm looking at this exactly to learn what I still don't know. Anyway, just to tell you, I'm working on something like the proposed dynarray, but multidimensional. A sort of dynarray2d, or dynarray3d, with the number of dimensions as a template parameter. The class is already working and I use it in production, I'm just adding allocator support. I don't think I'll have problems with iterator invalidation because, as the original dynarray, the size is fixed at construction (or am I missing something?)

Comment: "If two allocators compare equal, then either can deallocate pointers allocated from the other. Copies (either by copy construction or copy assignment) are required to compare equal." I found the source for the first sentence in the C++14 draft, but can you provide a reference for the second? It seems that in C++98 allocators were required to be stateless (ie. so any copy of an allocator could free another's allocation) but I'm not sure that that's still the case.

Comment: In fact GCC has an `alloc_trait` for whether allocators always compare equal (`_S_always_equal()`): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a00951_source.html indicating that it might not always be the case.

Comment: @TedPercival:  The requirement is in the "post-condition" column of Table 28 in the Allocator requirements section.  See the rows for copy construction and move construction.